# Print value from key in bash associative array

Tags: array

I'm trying to match the first three characters of a specific hostname to a key in an associative array. And then print the matching value. The code I have below prints all the values in the array.

```
!/bin/bash
host=$(hostname | cut -c1-3)

declare -A dc
dc=(
    [loc]="http://loc.example.com"
    [vr1]="http://vr1.example.com"
)

for K in "${!dc[@]}"
        do if [ $host == $K ];
 then echo "${dc[@]}" 
 fi
done
```

Comment: Hello Jdon1. Which bit of your problem are you struggling to solve? What's your question?

Comment: ... replace `echo "${dc[@]}"` by `echo "${dc[$K]}"` ?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver